# Can I force applications to run in a different locale to the system setting?

Tags: localization, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am developing a C# .NET 6 client-server product using VS2022 with multi-language support. I've set up locale-specific resource strings but at the last minute I realized a problem: while client workstations are set up in local language, *the app-server is always in English* - so back-end code is using the English localization!

Servers are in English for a good reason (and we can't change this) so is there a way to force a deployed application to use a specified locale? Perhaps in a config file somewhere?

I know I can do this in code by changing `Thread.CurrentCulture`  or similar, but the whole point is I don't want to hard-code it, I want it to be config-driven in a way that overrides the default system setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it to be config-driven in a way that overrides the default system setting.

You can always add custom setting to your config file and then read it on start up and set needed culture.

For example something like this:

- `appsettings.json`

```json
{
    "LocaleOverride" : "en-US",
    // rest of settings
}
```

And somewhere at the start of app (depends on how it is started, if generic/minimal hosting is used, configuration can be read from there, otherwise - manually):

```cs
var locale = Configuration["LocaleOverride"];
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(locale))
{
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(locale);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing - I was wondering if this was a built-in feature to save me the work :)